# Why Numpy and Scipy QR decomposition give me different values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

I have the following vector.

```
x = np.array([[ 0.87695113],
              [ 0.3284933 ],
              [-0.35078323]])
```

When I call numpy version of qr

```
from numpy.linalg import qr as qr_numpy
qr_numpy(x)
```

I obtain

```
(array([[-0.87695113],
        [-0.3284933 ],
        [ 0.35078323]]), array([[-1.]]))
```

whereas when I run the scipy version I get something entirely different.

```
from scipy.linalg import qr as qr_scipy
qr_scipy(x)
```

With output

```
(array([[-0.87695113, -0.3284933 ,  0.35078323],
        [-0.3284933 ,  0.94250897,  0.06139208],
        [ 0.35078323,  0.06139208,  0.93444215]]), array([[-1.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]]))
```

What is going on??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `mode` for [`numpy.linalg.qr()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) is `'reduced'` whereas for [`scipy.linalg.qr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html) it's `'full'`.

So to get the same results for both, either use `'economic'` for scipy-qr or `'complete'` for numpy-qr:

```py
from numpy.linalg import qr as qr_numpy
qr_numpy(x)
```

```
(array([[-0.87695113],
        [-0.3284933 ],
        [ 0.35078323]]),
 array([[-1.]]))
```

Which matches with the output of scipy-qr:

```py
from scipy.linalg import qr as qr_scipy
qr_scipy(x, mode='economic')
```

```
(array([[-0.87695113],
        [-0.3284933 ],
        [ 0.35078323]]),
 array([[-1.]]))
```

---

And to get the "complete" version with both:

```py
from numpy.linalg import qr as qr_numpy
qr_numpy(x, mode='complete')
```

```
(array([[-0.87695113, -0.3284933 ,  0.35078323],
        [-0.3284933 ,  0.94250897,  0.06139208],
        [ 0.35078323,  0.06139208,  0.93444215]]),
 array([[-1.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]]))
```

```py
from scipy.linalg import qr as qr_scipy
qr_scipy(x)
```

```
(array([[-0.87695113, -0.3284933 ,  0.35078323],
        [-0.3284933 ,  0.94250897,  0.06139208],
        [ 0.35078323,  0.06139208,  0.93444215]]),
 array([[-1.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]]))
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any resource to learn about what is the difference between them? Also I just noticed that if I use `svd` from numpy I get the same result but 3 times faster

Comment: @Euler_Salter Actually, to find the answer to your question, I just read the documentation of the two functions, linked in the answer. I haven't used them before :-) The numpy docs have some notes about the methods. The scipy docs mention _"This is an interface to the LAPACK routines dgeqrf, zgeqrf, dorgqr, zungqr, dgeqp3, and zgeqp3."_ Perhaps the wiki will point you to further info about it: [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).